# how to keep displaying photos even though the values ​don't match in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have a photo file in the public folder that has been given a previous name, so I display photos by combining the values, I want to keep displaying photos that do not match the photo file names with almost the same file names and ignore the values ​​that do not match

my controller

```
public function test(){

    $product = DB::table('t_test')->get();

    //dd($product);

    return view('test',compact('product'));
}
```

my blade

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($product as $p)
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="{{ asset('product/product_' . $p->item . '_' . $p->material . '_' . $p->type . '.jpg') }}">
                <p>Product Name : {{ $p->item }}</p>
                <p>Material : {{ $p->material }}</p>
                <p>Type : {{ $p->type }}</p>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

my table

| item | material | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| table | wood | 001 |
| table | frame | 001 |
| table | wood | 002 |
| table | alumunium | 001 |
| table | alumunium | 002 |

file foto on public folder

> product_table_wood_001.jpg

> product_table_frame_001.jpg

> product_table_alumunium_001.jpg

if I look at the inspect element from row 3 and 5 code it looks like this

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="{{ asset('product/product_table_wood_002.jpg') }}">
                <p>Product Name : {{ $p->item }}</p>
                <p>Material : {{ $p->material }}</p>
                <p>Type : {{ $p->type }}</p>
            </div>

<div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="{{ asset('product/product_table_alumunium_002.jpg') }}">
                <p>Product Name : {{ $p->item }}</p>
                <p>Material : {{ $p->material }}</p>
                <p>Type : {{ $p->type }}</p>
            </div>
```

there is no photo in public file with this name
, when this happens I still want to display the photo row 3 = "product_table_wood_001" and row 5 = "product_table_alumunium_001" because it has the closest value

the logic is something like this but I don't know how to write the correct way so that the code can run

```
@if (file_exists(public_path('product/thumb/thumb_' . $product->item . '')))
@if (file_exists(public_path('product/thumb/thumb_' . $product->item . ' ' . $product->material . '')))
    @if (file_exists(public_path('product/thumb/thumb_' . $product->item . ' ' . $product->material . ' ' . $product->type . '.jpg')))
        <img src="{{ asset('assets/product/thumb/thumb_table_wood_001.jpg') }}">
    @else {{-- showing one of the pictures of almost the same first name --}}
        <img src="{{ asset('assets/product/thumb/thumb_table_wood') }}"> @endif
@else
    {{-- showing one of the pictures of almost the same first name --}}
    <img src="{{ asset('assets/product/thumb/thumb_table') }}">@endif @else <img src="{{ asset('assets/product/thumb/no-photo.jpg') }}"> @endif
```

Comment: please share your model and migration

Comment: can you show  an example where the comination of values does not match? You should basically write a function which get the path, and handle that logic there.

Comment: @RachnaGajjar I made it directly without using migration because for testing and calling the table with the Laravel query builder

Comment: @MátyásGrőger I've added the code when the file doesn't match, I haven't found the right way for this problem

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following. In the Product model write a function to get the photo url:

```
public function getPhotoUrl()
{
    if (file_exists(asset('product/product_' . $this->item . '_' . $this->material . '_' . $this->type . '.jpg'))) {
        return asset('product/product_' . $this->item . '_' . $this->material . '_' . $this->type . '.jpg');
    } else {
        return asset('product/product_' . $this->item . '_' . $this->material . '_001' . '.jpg');
    }     
}
```

And in the view you simply call this function:

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ($product as $p)
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="{{ $p->getPhotoUrl() }}">
                <p>Product Name : {{ $p->item }}</p>
                <p>Material : {{ $p->material }}</p>
                <p>Type : {{ $p->type }}</p>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: thanks for your respons,
if I write else{return } like that eats all data that does not have a photo will appear with that photo, I want to display a photo with almost the same name, is it possible to check every "_" sign ?

Comment: I edited the else of my answer. Like that if the file does not exists, it will take  the file with same item and material but with type 001

Comment: Have you been able to resolve the issue in the meanwhile?